# How do I install strace on DragonFly BSD os?

Tags: freebsd, bsd, strace, dragonfly-bsd

How do I install strace debugging tool on DragonFly BSD os?
I have just starting hacking dragonfly os. I was wondering how do I install strace debugging tool on OS.

Answer (score 3):

`strace` is not available on DragonFly BSD. However, you may use `ktrace(1)`/`kdump(1)` or `truss(1)` instead which are part of the tools in base.